# Form Submit without Refreshing using Plugin (malsup)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I just created a form submit without refreshing using this plugin : http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

The simple example can be seen at 
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

I don't what I was doing, it was worked fine before until I modified something that I don't remember.

When I click SAVE, it should be processed on the background and it should stay on the same page. But now, it doesn't and it redirect me to the action page (process-001.php)

I created another page using the same method, and it works just fine.

Can you see if I'm doing it wrong?

Here is the form :

```
<div id="submit-form">
<form action="web-block/forms/process-001.php" id="select-block" class="general-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input-wrap">
    <input class="clearme" name="Headline" value="<?php echo $Headline;?>" id="headline"/>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
    <textarea class="clearme" name="Sub-Headline" id="subheadline"><?php echo $SubHeadline ;?></textarea>
</div>
<label>Bottom Left Image</label>
<div class="up-mask">
    <span class="file-wrapper">
      <input type="file" name="Pics" class="photo" id="pics" />
      <span class="button">
         <span class="default-txt">Upload Photo</span>
      </span>
    </span>
</div><!-- .up-mask -->

<input type="hidden" name="Key" id="Key" value="<?php echo $Key;?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="SAVE" />
<span class="save-notice">Your changed has been saved!</span>
</form>
</div>
```

The Javascript :

```
<script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#select-block').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you set this up in JSFiddle (or a similar site) so we can see it in action?

Comment: It's working now. I don't why but by changing form id from "select-block" to "Frm001" solves the problem...